# Can you submit new packages to existing Debian releases?

Tags: debian

I read that current Debian testing release "Debian Stretch" is frozen. Does it mean that it is not possible to submit new packages for this release?

What about current stable release "Debian Jessie"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s correct; since the soft freeze on January 5, 2017, new packages (as in, packages of new software which wasn’t already in Debian) aren’t accepted in Stretch. You’ll find more details in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/301455/86440) to [Debian testing, caveats with feature freeze?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/301449/86440).

Once a Debian release is frozen, it remains so for ever, so this applies to Jessie too. The only “Debian” way to make new packages available to users is to make them available *via* [backports](https://backports.debian.org), or some other repository (*e.g.* the [Debian Mozilla team repository](http://mozilla.debian.net/)). Note that backports can only be “fed” from the current release in preparation, so now that Stretch is frozen, new packages can’t enter Jessie backports (in theory).